# Which is the best platform to build highly loaded web api?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, architecture

I've read a lot of information on this topic and we are about to choose technology for future project, but I am still hesitating.
The project is the system of transfering data between portable device (iPhone, for example) and web-server through internet. Device requests for data, using http route and retrieves data in JSON format.
When we decided to use asp.net mvc application we encountered with heavy critic from side of another developers. They argumented, that asp.net is very slow and expensive platform for such purposes.
Please, explain, is it right? If it is, which platform would be better? Mb Php?

`Added:`
Every device should send about 40 requests a minute. It can be up to 20.000 devices "online" at one moment.

Comment: this type of question is too subjective. you're not giving precise requirements so pretty much anyones favorite framework would fit the bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has the potential to be one of those religious arguments about which framework is better. All I'll say is that there are a lot of good frameworks out there, and ASP.Net MVC is one of them. Also bear in mind that for an API it's primarily the code behind that will full-fill the functionality, eg. C#.

ASP.NET supports both Webforms and MVC, and both will do the job. I think you can be confident that C# will be able to provide you with all your API needs. It has a strong data layer, and various ways to serialize your data into JSON or XML, or both..

In order of preference this is how I would choose your framework:

**Skills:** What developer skills do I have? Pick the framework that you'll be able to develop and maintain easily.

**Serialization:** Can my framework serialize data into JSON and XML with minimal work. C# can serialize a class object with pretty much one line of code. Or you can do it manually too, which is what we do a lot of the time.

**Data Layer:**  Where will my data sit, and how will I handle it. Typically you'll be using a SQL database with some kind of framework on top of it, such as Entity Framework, SQL Client, Datasets, etc. Plenty of options with C# here again.

**Speed:** I can't say that I agree with C# being slow. There is a bit of overhead with the front-end components of ASP.NET, but these can easily be optimized. A single MVC server can easily scale to millions of requests a day if coded correctly.

I must stress that ASP.NET is only one of many good options. There are other great frameworks out there too, and I'm sure others will share their experiences with them. It's important you get your developers to buy into the direction, as their passion will have to go into it.

Out of interest, which framework do they want to use..?

Comment: Great Dave, thanks. We discussed about PHP and Ruby on Rails, but I sure, that the system will grow very fast and it will be much more difficult to support it if we choose one of them. So, I think about asp.net mvc for now.

Comment: PHP and Ruby are both very good too. If you have strong developer skills in either of these then you should definitely consider them too..

Answer (score 2):

Don't just talk about technologies and argue with other developers. Create a prototype and put it under realistic load. That's the only way to see whether a certain technology is capable of handling the low.

Everything else is mainly based on hear saying, personal preferences, out-dated knowledge, religious belief etc.

Comment: Thanks, Codo. May be we'll try to build some work prototypes before real work. But can you make fast assumption, what will be better/faster?

Comment: It's very difficult from your short description as you don't give any details what the server has to do. Does it involve storage of data? Is it just JSON or some HTML as well? Does it involve access to other services and servers? Does it involve some messaging between clients? From the very short description I'd say: The load isn't trivial but doable with either ASP.NET or Java technologies. And "asp.net is very slow" is certainly a very biased opinion.

Answer (score 1):

One **objective** reason to avoid asp.net is that asp.net is not portable to another non-Windows platform, like Linux. If you ever want to move to Linux, then asp.net suddenly will become *very* expensive because you will have to rewrite a large part of your software.

Comment: Objective - yes; but not necessarily answering the "highly loaded" part of the question.  Granted it might be cheaper to scale-out licence-wise on linux.

Comment: Now almost ten years later, .NET core is portable and runs very fast on linux servers.